# What does :host /deep/ selector mean?

Tags: css, angular, shadow-dom

Please explain in a straightforward way what `:host /deep/` means:

```
:host /deep/ .ui-autocomplete {
  width: 85%;
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is used to allow styling child components when using `emulated` view encapsulation.

More about this can be found here:

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Btw `/deep/` selector is now deprecated:

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with the tools.

`:host` is used to address the hosting element - that is the one that you use to add the component somewhere (e.g. `<app-component>`).

> Use the :host pseudo-class selector to target styles in the element that hosts the component (as opposed to targeting elements inside the component's template).

So the selector `:host /deep/ .ui-autocomplete` means "on current hosting element, go deep (search in child components too) and look for elements with class `ui-autocomplete`.

Here is some additional information about the view encapsulation feature:

https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html