# Access parent css from grand child

Tags: angular

Consider this scenario:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="theme">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**app.component.scss**

```
.theme {
  ...   
  .just-test {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Now, when component **grandChild.component.html**  (`grandchild of App component`) will be loaded via routing (the parent component of **grandChild** is actually the component loaded and the one that contains grandChild), it seems it has no access to class `"just-test"`.

**grandChild.component.html**

```
<div class="just-test">Hello mate</div>
```

*Is it possible to access "**just-test**" and how?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Because each component has its css encapsulated. Take a look here: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

What you can do, however, is set this rule in the styles.scss (or style.css) in the root folder of your app. Those are not encapsulated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:host /deep/ .just-test {...}` inside your `grandChild.component.scss`.

Any rules you apply to that, will overwrite the original class definition.

Comment: :host /deep/ is used to allow styling child components, not to use a selector from a parent. Plus, the /deep/ selector is deprecated. You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914414/what-does-host-deep-selector-mean

Comment: I didn't understand the child styling part, but regarding the deprecation, although it is true, there are several cases where /deep/ is the only functional syntax.

Comment: Because you said that he can use `:host /deep/` in the `grandChild.component.scss`; he wants to define the rule in the parent, in this case, the app.component.css