# how change style grid in angular 6

Tags: css, angular, grid

I have this style:

```
.main-panel{
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 4rem auto;
  grid-template-columns: 14rem auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header''sidebar body';
}
```

Now how do I change the style grid-template-areas in angular

for example :

```
grid-template-columns: 14rem auto;
grid-template-areas: 'header header''sidebar body';

to >>>

grid-template-columns: 100%;
grid-template-areas: 'header header''sidebar sidebar';
```

Doesn't angular support styles from css grid????!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your HTML?
Maybe you need to target :host /deep/

like that:

[What does :host /deep/ selector mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46914414/what-does-host-deep-selector-mean][1])

Answer (score 1):

You can create two class, and dynamic change class of an element.
example
css

```
.A{
grid-template-columns: 14rem auto;
grid-template-areas: 'header header''sidebar body';
}

.B{
grid-template-columns: 100%;
grid-template-areas: 'header header''sidebar sidebar';
}
```

in HTML

```
<div [ngClass]="{
 'A': isA,
 'B': isB
}"></div>
```